# Replace NA each column based on another vector using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

I am trying to replace NAs in a data.frame of many columns using another vector in which the replacement values for each column are given. I know how I could replace each value using a function, but not to find the value in another vector. I am searching for a dplyr approach:

For example:

```
require(dplyr)
test <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,NA), B = c(4,5,NA,2), C = c(NA,2,2,NA), D = c(1,2,3,4))
replace_na <- c(A = 100, B = 200, C = 300)
# Replace with median should be replace with look up value in vector based on the name of the vector or position
test %>% mutate_each_(funs(replace(., is.na(.), median(.,na.rm = T))), names(replace_na))
expected_result <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,100), B = c(4,5,200,2), C = c(300,2,2,300), D = c(1,2,3,4))
> expected_result
    A   B   C  D
1   1   4 300  1
2   2   5   2  2
3   3 200   2  3
4 100   2 300  4
```

Comment: There are some typos in the new example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is as easy as using `replace_na` function from `tidyr`-package:

```
library(tidyr)
test %>% replace_na(as.list(replacements))
```

The output:

```
    A   B   C D
1   1   4 300 1
2   2   5   2 2
3   3 200   2 3
4 100   2 300 4
```

This function needs a list for which columns the NA's you want to replace. So, it is possible to replace for only selected columns. Example:

```
replacements2 <- list(B = 200, C = 300)
test %>% replace_na(replacements2)
```

output:

```
   A   B   C D
1  1   4 300 1
2  2   5   2 2
3  3 200   2 3
4 NA   2 300 4
```

As you can see, only the NA's for the B and C columns are replaced.

Data:

```
test <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,NA), B = c(4,5,NA,2), C = c(NA,2,2,NA), D = c(1,2,3,4))
replacements <- c(A = 100, B = 200, C = 300)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Map` from `base R`

```
test[names(replace_na)] <- Map(function(x,y) 
      replace(x, is.na(x), y), test[names(replace_na)], replace_na)
test
#    A   B   C D
#1   1   4 300 1
#2   2   5   2 2
#3   3 200   2 3
#4 100   2 300 4
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>% 
   select_at(names(replace_na)) %>%
   map2_df(., replace_na, ~replace(., is.na(.), .y)) %>%
   bind_cols(., select_at(test, setdiff(names(test), names(replace_na))))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
#      A     B     C     D
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     4   300     1
#2     2     5     2     2
#3     3   200     2     3
#4   100     2   300     4
```

---

Or with `set` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)
for(j in names(replace_na)){
  set(test, i = which(is.na(test[[j]])), j = j, value = replace_na[j])
 }

test
#     A   B   C D
#1:   1   4 300 1
#2:   2   5   2 2
#3:   3 200   2 3
#4: 100   2 300 4
```

Comment: Almost there, the problem is that these functions loops over all columns while I want to select only the columns which are the names of replace_na

Comment: I like the tidyverse approach the most since I can incorporate it in a dplyr chain, but could not find a solution such that it works for these colums I tried the following which is close I think: test %>% mutate_at(.cols = names(replace_na),
                   .funs = funs(map2_df(., replace_na, ~replace(.x, is.na(.x), .y))))